# Visual Studio 2022: DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80070005]

Tags: visual-studio, maui

I have this problem every time I try to debug my MAUI app on Windows Machine. It looks like this:

```
DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80070005] Deployment Register operation with target volume D: on Package 4C30989C-021C-4C65-A99F-1EF165615662_1.0.0.1_x64_9n4h1lOyvjzm from: (AppxManifest.xml) failed with error 0x80070005. See http:// ClickerSomethingTestApp go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?Linkld=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.
```

This happens on both new and excisting projects.

Edit:
I moved project folder to default visual studio projects location and now it works. Also works anywhere on C drive. However I want my projects on D drive. Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3485

Comment: please do not post code or errors as images

Comment: @HansPassant I tried this solution and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same issue and found that the permissions for the project directory were wrong.

I believe this is due to the fact that I don't run my projects from the default Visual Studio location.

The fix for me was to use `File Explorer` to navigate to the location of the project directory. Then right click the project directory and choose `Properties`.

When the properties window opens choose the `Security` tab and in the `Group or user names:` section select both the `System` user and your personal user and make sure the `Permissions` section shows `Full Control` and all other permissions are checked.

If full control is not enabled click the `Edit` button and on the new `Permissions` window that opens choose the `Allow` box for `Full Control` and then click `OK` to apply the changes.

As soon as I allowed Full Control my app worked flawlessly.

Comment: Was having this running VS 2022 under Parallels on my Mac - this (changing bin folder to a local folder inside the Windows VM), fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your project is on a network drive and adjusting the permissions on the network drive is not an option for you, I was able to solve this issue by simply changing the build output directory to a local one.

Go to the properties of the project. In the left panel open the Build menu and click Output. Under "Base output path" browse to a local directory where you want to build and click OK.

This was enough in my situation to get the Windows app to build and run locally. It creates the bin and obj files on the network drive but will copy dist folders (Debug and Release) on the local machine. If this still gives you problems, you may need to further adjust the "Base intermediates output path" in the properties (just below the Base output path setting describes above).